# How to display one questions at one page in django template?

Tags: django

I am creating a mcqs based app where I have to create display one questions on each page and when the users answers that question I want to redirect it to next question, but I am quite confused how to apply this logic?

I am getting all the questions in
questions = Question.objects.all()
this is my templates file

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-danget mt-3">
        <h3>Simple Js/Python App</h3>
        <hr>
        <table>
            {% for i in questions %}
            <tr>
                <td class="text-primary">{{forloop.counter }}) {{i.question_text}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% for j in i.get_answers %}

            <tr>
                <td> <input type="radio" class="rb"> {{j.options}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %} {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: if u want to do that create seperate views as well as seperate pages then it will appear one question on single page

Comment: another option is using the form wizard package which support form on multiple page https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html

Comment: I am sorry, didnt get it. Should I sent only one question to the template? and after getting the response I should send next one?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same URL for all questions: something like

```
'question/<int:qnumber>', QuestionView.as_view(), name='question_bynum')
```

Display the question identified by kwargs['qnumber']. The user inputs or selects his answer. On submit, the answer gets stored and the user is redirected appropriately:

```
 qnumber += 1
 return redirect( 'myapp:question_bynum', qnumber=qnumber )
```

You will want to think about navigation options so that the user can also go back to previous questions and change his answers (assuming that's permitted). For example, get a question number to go to from the user in a different view, and redirect as above but with `qnumber = goto`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question but here my solution for next users

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{%load static%}

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
       
        body {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }

        #regForm {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            margin: 100px auto;
            font-family: Raleway;
            padding: 40px;
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 300px;
        }

        /* Hide all steps by default: */
        .tab {
            display: none;
        }

        button {
            background-color: #04AA6D;
            color: #ffffff;
            border: none;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 17px;
            font-family: Raleway;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        button:hover {
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        #prevBtn {
            background-color: #bbbbbb;
        }

        /* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
        .step {
            height: 15px;
            width: 15px;
            margin: 0 2px;
            background-color: #bbbbbb;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }

        .step.active {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        /* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
        .step.finish {
            background-color: #04AA6D;
        }
        #pleaseWaitDiv {
        display: none;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .spinner {
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        margin: 20px auto;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
        border-top: 5px solid #3498db;
        animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes spin {
        0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
        100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
    </style>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <style>
        ol.breadcrumb li+li:before {
          content: '\f061';
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'fontAwesome';
        padding: 0 10px;
        }
        </style>
</head>


    <h3 style="text-align: center;">{{ptseexam.ptseexam_name}}</h3>

    <form id="regForm" method='post' onsubmit="submitForm(); return false;">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <div align="right " id="displaytimer"><b>Timer: 0 seconds</b></div>

        {% for q in questions%}
        <div class="tab">
            {% if q.is_equation %}
             <img src="https://latex.codecogs.com/png.image?{{q.question}}">
                    {% else %}
                    {{q.question}}
                    {% endif %}
            <p><input type="radio" name="{{q.question}}" checked id="gridRadios1" value="option1">
                <label for="gridRadios1">
                    {% if q.is_equation %}
                     <img src="https://latex.codecogs.com/png.image?{{q.option1}}">
                    {% else %}
                    {{q.option1}}
                    {% endif %}
                </label>
            </p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="{{q.question}}" id="gridRadios1" value="option2">
                <label for="gridRadios1">
                    {% if q.is_equation %}
                    <img src="https://latex.codecogs.com/png.image?{{q.option2}}">
                    {% else %}
                    {{q.option2}}
                    {% endif %}
                </label>
            </p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="{{q.question}}" id="gridRadios1" value="option3">
                <label for="gridRadios1">
                    {% if q.is_equation %}
                    <img src="https://latex.codecogs.com/png.image?{{q.option3}}">
                    {% else %}
                    {{q.option3}}
                    {% endif %}
                </label>
            </p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="{{q.question}}" id="gridRadios1" value="option4">
                <label for="gridRadios1">
                    {% if q.is_equation %}
                     <img src="https://latex.codecogs.com/png.image?{{q.option4}}">
                    {% else %}
                    {{q.option4}}
                    {% endif %}
                </label>
            </p>
        </div>

        {% endfor %}
        <div>
            {% for q in questions%}
            <span class="step"></span>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div style="overflow:auto;">
            <div style="float:right;">
                <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
                <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input id='timer' type='hidden' name="timer" value="">
    </form>
    <div id="pleaseWaitDiv">
        <p>Please wait...</p>
        <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var currentTab = 0;
        showTab(currentTab);
    
        function showTab(n) {
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
            x[n].style.display = "block";
    
            if (n == 0) {
                document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
            }
    
            if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
                document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
            }
    
            fixStepIndicator(n);
        }
    
        function nextPrev(n) {
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
            x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
            currentTab = currentTab + n;
    
            if (currentTab >= x.length) {
                showPleaseWait(); // Show "Please wait" before submitting
                document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
                return false;
            }
    
            showTab(currentTab);
        }
    
        function fixStepIndicator(n) {
            var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
    
            x[n].className += " active";
        }
    
        function showPleaseWait() {
            var pleaseWaitDiv = document.getElementById("pleaseWaitDiv");
            pleaseWaitDiv.style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
    
{% block script %}
<script>

    console.log('hello world')
    const timer = document.getElementById('displaytimer')
    console.log(timer.textContent)
    const inputtag = document.getElementById('timer')
    t = 0
    setInterval(() => {
        t += 1
        timer.innerHTML = "<b>Timer: " + t + " seconds</b>"
        inputtag.value = t
    }, 1000)
</script>
{% endblock script %}
{% endblock %}

</div>
```